# Service for example status code responses

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I'm working on testing curl against some different responses (502's, 404's, 401's, etc.).  It would be fairly trivial to set something custom up that I could hit and get pre-defined responses from, but if there's a service out there it'll save me the time.

Comment: See http://httpstat.us/ and http://httpbin.org/

Comment: Hi @BenZittlau which service did you use for this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of Sripathi's answers are excellent tools.  I wish he had answered so I could award the answer to him:

> See [httpstat.us](http://httpstat.us) and [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org)